# IPv4 addresses in different encodings

Tags: ip

Trying to work out if I should have any security concerns with being able to do the following:

IPv4 addresses can be represented in different ways:

```
$ ping 0177.1
$ ping 134744072
$ ping 0x8080808
$ ping 010.0x0000008.00000010.8
$ ping 8.0x0000000000000080808
```

This works on both, Linux and Windows.  I assume that next-generation firewalls are able to detect this and 'block'?

Original reference: https://twitter.com/x0rz/status/928584447292858368?s=03

Comment: What makes you think that this has anything to do with the IP address? It's more likely about `gethostbyname()` and similar APIs trying to be "helpful". Try `nslookup 8.0x0000000000000080808` for one.

Comment: here's your test: do a packet capture when you try different encodings of an IP: do the different encodings get passed along to the network?

Comment: if you are going to copy/paste someone else, at least provide credit: https://twitter.com/x0rz/status/928584447292858368

Comment: Yes it has potential impact - encodings of IP's can be used to evade filters for XSS, SSRF, etc.

Answer (score 2):

this is a false premise.

Firewalls work by parsing the IP's provided on there own predictable way. 
The underlying protocols only use the Network Bitwise implementation of an IP address (e.a. it uses the 32 or 128 bit representation, for ipv4 and ipv6 respectively).

The underlying libraries that ping uses to make the connect translate the given representation to the expected representation by the system.

This means that there is no difference for the firewall between the IP representations

to illustrate this I ran the ping command with the address you supplied and captured the systemcalls. here is the results for the connect call on linux.

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, 16) = 0
```

As you can see only the dotted decimal notation was used for the call.